# History of "Bulls and Cows"

Tags: puzzle-history, mastermind

[Bulls and Cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) is a game that predates [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) but is closely related.   The wikipedia has for first dates of Mastermind as 1970.

> What is the earliest reference to the game Bulls and Cows?

Comment: You could mark the Wikipedia page as `[citation needed]` and let that community work on it as well.

Comment: Are such questions allowed? Questions tagged `puzzle-history` are about the history of puzzles. I have never seen a question asking about the history of a game...

Comment: @Hackerdarshi exactly flag it.

Comment: I believe this is a perfectly legit question, about puzzling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [codebreaker-mastermind-superhirn.blogspot.co.uk](http://codebreaker-mastermind-superhirn.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/bulls-and-cows-mastermind-superhirn.html)

> The exact year when the number guessing game Bulls and Cows was invented is not known. "Bulls and Cows has been played as a paper-and-pencil game for a century or more. I first played a computer version in 1968 on Titan, the Cambridge University Atlas" (John Francis, 2010 [dead link to "Bulls and cows.pdf"]).
>
> A similar word guessing game "Jotto was invented in 1955 by Morton M. Rosenfeld and marketed by his New York-based Jotto Corp." ([wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jotto))